# How to show large amount of information with the vscode api?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently I have command that does text transformation. Sometimes this could be large, so I want to be able to let the user see the changes and include the stats.

How would I do this?

First thing I tried was `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` but that's not multiline.

The next thing I though of was opening a read only file, but I want to avoid creating a temporary file if possible. Plus I could not find a way to open in read only mode.

Lastly I found the [Webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#should-i-use-a-webview) but they recommend not using it unless absolute necessary. So is there another more optimal way?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using a WebView.

Comment: They have a whole section on being cautious with usage, 'Webviews are resource heavy and run in a separate context from normal extensions. A poorly designed webview can also easily feel out of place within VS Code.' But since it's opt-in and I can't find an alternative, I guess I'll use one for now.